# Direct sum of two additive groups with different modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

When I read " the structure of rings" by Jacobson at page 83, I have a question that if two  extension of  modules $M$  and $N$ is isomorphic, does they have equivalent factor set?

Consequently, I am trying to find a conterexample like the following.

Assume that $M$ and $N$ are right unitary $R$ modules. We use $(M\oplus N)_1$ to represent the direct sum of the two modules. We define another module structure $(M\oplus N)_2$ over the direct sum of the two additive group $M\oplus N$ such that $(m\oplus 0)\circ r = mr\oplus 0$, $(0\oplus n)\circ r =r(n)\oplus nr$ where $ r\in R $ and $r(n) \in M$. It is obvious that $r(n_1+n_2)=r(n_1)+r(n_2)$ and $(r_1r_2)(n)=r_2(n)r_1+r_1(nr_2)$.

If there exists an isomorphism of module $ \varphi :(M\oplus N)_1 \rightarrow (M\oplus N)_2$, does there exists a submodule $W$ of $(M\oplus N)_2$ such that $W\cap M =\{0\}$ and the identity mapping $Id : (M\oplus N)_2 \rightarrow M+W=(M\oplus N)_2$ is isomorphic of modules?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking. The direct sum viewed as direct sum of modules, abelian groups, etc shouldn't be any different because a sum is a direct sum if $M\cap N=\{0\}$. This condition doesn't change depending on the algebraic structure we are looking at.

Comment: @daruma The direct sum of two abelian group is an abelian group. But we can define different module structures in the same group.

Comment: @daruma The direct sum of two module is one natural module structure over the direct sum of the two abelian group.

Comment: You already have a $R$-module structure on $M$ and $N$. Then, $M\oplus N$ is just the direct sum in whichever category you pick. Are you asking if we have two abelian groups and we put different module structures, will their direct sums be isomorphic as modules? If that is the case, this shouldn't be true.

Comment: @daruma.I know this is a little confusing.  I mean $M$ and $N$ hava been two right  $R$ modules. So I use $(M\oplus N)_1$  to represent the direct sun of the two modules in order to distinguish it with the direct sum of the two groups $M\oplus N$. But We can get a lot of  module structures in the group $M\oplus N$ by the module $M$ and $N$. It is the factor set which is defined in Jacobson's book...

Comment: @daruma I have edited it again.

Comment: If $M_1$ and $M_2$ are isomorphic abelian groups with different module structure, the identity map may not even be a module homomorphism. Take $R=k[t]$ and $M_1,M_2$ to be $R$. We have two distinct module structures namely, $t\cdot m=tm$ or $t\cdot m=m$ (i.e. the variable $t$ acts naturally or trivially). So, if $f=\textrm{id}$ then, $m=f(m)=f(tm)\neq tf(m)=tm$. (For example, take $N=0$ in your question and this map you wrote isn't even a homomorphism).

Comment: @daruma  I mean $(M\oplus N)_2$ =$ M\oplus W$. $W$ and $M$ are submodules of $(M\oplus N)_2$. So the identity mapping is from  $(M\oplus N)_2$ to itself.

Comment: The identity map is an honest homomorphism if you have the same module structure on both sides. But if you have different module structures, the identity map is not even in homomorphism as discussed above. And usually, when we use the word identity map, we reserve that for cases where you have the same algebraic structure (same module structure, group structure, etc) in the source and your target.

Comment: @daruma Yes but I don't know the existence of $W$...

Comment: What is $r(n)$ in your question?

Comment: @runway44 $r(n)$ is an element in $M$ that makes $(M\oplus N)_2$ a right $R$ module.